# Is there a defined precedence for multiple matching profiles in Spring Boot application.yaml files?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm working on migrating an app to new hosting infrastructure.

I currently have profiles like this defined:

- `dev`
- `qa`
- `prod`

Each of those have corresponding bits of configuration for things like JMS brokers, etc.

I'm now working on building a new proof of concept instance of this app on new hosting infrastructure.

I'm looking to keep the on-prem instances working unchanged (no need adjust their active profiles), but will add an additional `cloud` profile to my instances on the new hosting.

My goal is to have config like this work, but I'm not having much luck yet:

For the app itself, run it with `spring.profiles.active=dev,cloud` instead of `spring.profiles.active=dev` like I do now.

In my `application.yaml`:

```
---
# default config, applicable to all environments, goes here

---
spring:
  profiles: cloud

# config common to all hosts on this new hosting platform goes here

---
spring:
  profiles: cloud & dev

# this is the bit that isn't applying, but should have overrides of some details for when the dev env is on The Cloud

---
spring:
  profiles: dev

# the current on-prem dev instance; my goal is to have some config here apply both on prem and
# in the cloud, but have the cloud config override some of this in specific instances
```

---

The alternative solution I see is to go to the deployment config of all my on-prem instances, and add a new `on-prem` profile to each (e.g. `on-prem,dev`, `on-prem,qa`, & `on-prem,prod`), shift anything that's on-prem specific into new `on-prem & dev`, etc profiles in YAML, and keep the stuff that's common across both in a bare `dev` profile... maybe this is just what I need to do, but suggestions would be appreciated.