# Matching application.yaml file for two specific profiles

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-configuration

Relevant similar (unanswered) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60403540/is-there-a-defined-precedence-for-multiple-matching-profiles-in-spring-boot-appl)

I am having troubles implementing a simple configuration matrix for multi-tenant multi-environment Spring Boot application.

We have defined two *sets* of profiles: `country_[iso2]` (the tenant!), e.g. `country_uk`, `country_ro`, `country_de`; and the environment, `development`, `test`, `qa`, `prod`

The thing is I now need to inject some URLs that depend/change according to the **combination** tenant and environment. A matrix configuration.

And since there is a large number of properties to set, I haven't been following the approach of the linked answer, instead I have created multiple dash-separated-name files

- application.yaml (common for all)
- application-country_xx.yaml (all environments in `xx` share this)
- application-country_xx-development.yaml (supposed to match `country_xx & development`)
- etc.

When I start the application with either `country_xx`, `development`, or the opposite, I don't get the value for the property I have set. I am using `@ConfigurationProperties`.

In order not to end up with a huge single YAML file I don't like to merge every file into one and using the `spring.profiles` key. I prefer separate files.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Spring. Profiles are taken one at a time

[Source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/config/StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java#L153)

```java
private Set<StandardConfigDataReference> getProfileSpecificReferences(ConfigDataLocationResolverContext context,
            ConfigDataLocation[] configDataLocations, Profiles profiles) {
        Set<StandardConfigDataReference> references = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        for (String profile : profiles) {
            for (ConfigDataLocation configDataLocation : configDataLocations) {
                String resourceLocation = getResourceLocation(context, configDataLocation);
                references.addAll(getReferences(configDataLocation, resourceLocation, profile));
            }
        }
        return references;
    }
```

The above evaluates one profile at a time, not all the combinations